# How to redirect with headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

How i can redirect after my loginPost method with header Authorization(my jquery code):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $("#form-login").submit(function (event){
        event.preventDefault();

        let $form = $(this),
            email = $form.find("input[name='email'").val(),
            password = $form.find("input[name='password'").val();

        loginPost(email, password);

    })

    function loginPost(email, password) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"/api/auth/login",
            type:"POST",
            async:false,
            data: {email, password},
            success: function (data) {
                let urlLogin;
                if(data["role"] === "ROLE_USER") {
                    urlLogin = "/api/user"
                } else {
                    urlLogin = "/api/admin"
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url:urlLogin,
                    type:"GET",
                    async: false,
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer "+data["token"]
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Thymeleaf ViewController :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ViewController {

   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
   @RequestMapping("/user")
   public String userPage() {
       return "user_page";
   }
   
   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
   @GetMapping("/admin")
   public String adminPage() {
       return "admin_page";
   }

}
```

After get request i have only response with hmtl page, but i need to redirect get route with rendering this page.
If i doing window.location="/api/user" i have response 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you can change the page via
`window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";`. In your case I would suggest you to do something like `window.location.href = "http://www.yoururl.com" + urlLogin;` or something like this. If you want to redirect using just the php (on server side) you can do this by setting the `Location` header.
You can set the Location header by doing this:

```
$path = "/admin";
header("Location: " . $path);
```

or `header("Location: /admin");`

Have a nice day!

Comment: Just one thing, is there a mod rewritte for nginx too? If it is, is the same .htaccess valid? Thanks!